# Settings are gone if EXE changed path

Tags: c#

If i put my compiled .exe (with all other dlls and app config) to another path, the Properties.Settings will be reseted. 
How can i handle that?
I tried the Upgrade Method, but this is only for use setting files from older versions

The Settings are used Globally via `Properties.Settings.Default[property]` and saved on `formClosing` event via `Settings.Default.Save();`

Comment: can you show the source code where the settings are being read/saved

Comment: edited. i think there is no specific code for that because i use it almost globally

Comment: well how about a single line of code where a setting is read and another when is written

Comment: The setting are not gone, you just cannot ever find them back.  They are stored in a directory whose name is based on many things, including, the path and the EXE name.